# Entity Framework, Oracle and Identiity Column

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I am using Entitiy Framework with Oracle and I use sequences when I need autogenerated primary key columns. When I create the edmx file EF designer doesn't recognize this pattern so I need to insert StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" to the edmx file manually for all the identitiy columns. I repeat this each time I need to update my model. When the model gets big and updates are frequent this becomes to be time consuming.

I wonder if there is an easier method around this, like first time I add a table to the model I can add the line StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" to the edmx, but following updates add the line automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12c, you have the identity column.

```
SQL> drop table identity_table purge
  2  /

Table dropped.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE identity_table (
  2    ID          NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  3    txt        VARCHAR2(30)
  4  )
  5  /

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO identity_table(txt) VALUES('id number 1');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO identity_table(txt) VALUES('id number 1');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO identity_table(txt) VALUES('id number 1');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM identity_table;

        ID TXT
---------- ------------------------------
         1 id number 1
         2 id number 1
         3 id number 1

SQL>
```

Oracle actually creates a sequence for you, all you need to do is create an identity column `NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`.

Comment: Lalit, thanks for the answer but using Oracle 12c is not an option for me at the moment, 11g is used within the company at the moment.

I am ok with adding trigger and sequence myself but adding the storegeneratedpattern="identity" becomes a burden for complex models. What I am trying to do is avoiding putting this line manually each time I update the model, if possible.